# What does 'without affecting program' mean in the context of interfaces?

Tags: interface

Coding to an interface is argued to be a good practice, allowing for the possibility to change an object later without affecting program behavior, but why do we need to change something if it does not have an effect? I understand the flexibility that this practice gives, I just do not understand the definition.

Comment: You affect the program behavior, what you don't affect is the program structure. You'll won't have to change it.

Comment: Your information is basically wrong, so you can't draw any meaningful conclusions from it.  The term "interface" means something very specific in languages like Java or C#.  Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) for more info.   Also read about [Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) and [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 2):

They mean you are able to change the implementation of that class and you will be 100% sure the rest of the program isn't broken after the change. Because you do not change a single line outside of that class implementation. Of course you can break the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces doesn't just allow you to change the implementation of a class. It also allows you to change the class itself. Details after the break.

Interfaces also serve to reduce the mental effort needed to develop (and understand) complex code. If you can clearly define the interaction between two parts of your program then work can proceed on both parts *without one knowing how the other implements the interface*. This happy situation can continue until both parts are ready to be put together, when something called "integration testing" takes place.

Interface, in the sense described above, is quite an abstract concept. The signature of a function, for instance, is an "interface".

Other forms of interfaces are constructs that use the `interface` keyword (e.g. in Java or C#) or classes with pure virtual methods (in C++). When people say "programming to an interface" they usually refer to these constructs.

Not the best example in the world, but but suppose we have this:

```
interface ICooking
{
void Chop();
void Grill();
// other cooking functions
}
```

which is implemented by this class:

```
class Chef implements ICooking
{
void Chop()
{
...
}

void Grill()
{
...
}

// other cooking functions
}
```

And now you want to write a function that makes a steak. You will need someone to operate the kitchen (i.e. someone that implements ICooking).

You could write the function like this:

```
void MakeASteak( Chef ThePersonWhoCooks )
{
...
}
```

and call it as:

```
Chef Joe;

MakeASteak( Joe );
```

or you could write it like this:

```
void MakeASteak( ICooking ThePersonWhoCooks )
{
...
}
```

and call it as:

```
Chef Joe;

MakeASteak( Joe );
```

You should observe the following:

- you call `MakeASteak` exactly the same in both cases
- you can change the implementation of `Chef::Grill` and, as long as it still "grills" (e.g. you go from medium-rare to medium) you don't need to change the code in `MakeASteak`

This is one of the benefits of using a clearly defined interface. As long as the `Grill` method does what it is supposed to do, its callers don't need to know *how* it does it.

The second version is quite different. This is the one people have in mind when they say "program to an interface". It allows one to add this:

```
class HomeCook implements ICooking
{
void Chop()
{
...
}

void Grill()
{
...
}

// other cooking functions
}
```

and call

```
HomeCook AverageJoe;

MakeASteak( AverageJoe );
```

So, if the `MakeASteak` function only uses the methods defined in `ICooking` then not only does it not care *how* the `ICooking` functions are implemented, it also doesn't care *what* object implements the interface.

You can then also use complex objects:

```
Class ComplicatedPerson implements ICooking, IWriting, IActing, ISwimming
{
}
```

and use it just like before:

```
ComplicatedPerson person;
MakeASteak( person );
```

Another example would be the `std` algorithms that use iterators. The library writer only needs to know that the iterator "iterates" and can focus on the algorithm itself. The programmer responsible for writing the iterator code for a `vector` or for a `set` can focus on his code without having to worry about the `binary search` algorithm details. If both programmers do their job properly then the algorithm will be usable no matter what container provides the iterators.